# If $x_1-x_0,x_2-x_0,\ldots,x_{n-1}-x_0$ are linearly independent, show that there is exactly one plane containing all points $x_i$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> We are given $x_0, x_1, \ldots, x_{n-1}$ such that $x_1 - x_0, x_2 - x_0, \ldots, x_{n-1} - x_0$ form a linearly independent subset.  The question is to show that there is exactly one plane containing all the points $x_0, x_1, \ldots, x_{n-1}$.

If we know that the Euclidean space $E$ is $n$-dimensional, then let $W = \text{span} \{ \, x_i - x_0 \, \}$ and find $y \in W^{\perp}$.  The unique equation is given by $\langle \, x - x_0, y \, \rangle = 0$.  The choice of $y$ is unique because $W^{\perp}$ has dimension $1$.  But we weren't  told that the Euclidean space is $n$-dimensional, so I want to double-check.

If $\dim E > n$, then $W^{\perp}$ has dimension $2$ or more.  As a result, the equation definitely is not unique since there are more than one element orthonormal to $W$.  What I'm having some difficulty imagining is the case where $\dim E = n - 1$.  In this scenario, $W$ is the whole space and I don't see how you can have a plane holding all $n$ points.

Comment: I think you can safely assume that $\dim(E)=n$, but you're correct that the book should have explicitly said so.

Comment: What is the definition of "plane" here?

Comment: Actually, the text used the term hyperplane which, according to Wiki, has dimenion $n - 1$.  But no, the definition in my text did not explicitly say what the dimension should be.  Consider this solved.  Thanks!